# sort a comma-delimited string based on another in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets-formula

Based on a preferred order of a comma-delimited string as in the table below, how can a comma delimited string be re-ordered (if a value does not appear in the predefined list it will be outputted at the end)?

|  | Input | Output |  | Preferred Order |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  | red, orange, yellow, green, blue, dark blue, light blue, indigo, violet |
| 1 | orange, indigo, green | orange, green, indigo |  | {insert formula} |
| 2 | chicken, orange, violet, dark blue, blue, light blue | orange, blue, dark blue, light blue, violet, chicken |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
=byrow(A3:A,lambda(z,if(z="",,let(Σ,split(z,", ",0),join(", ",sort(tocol(Σ),tocol(index(xmatch(Σ,split(C2,", ",0)))),1))))))
```

[image]